# weak_ptr<User_Class> is none pointer type

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I used ordinary pointers in my project. I had some problems with memory and changed ordinary pointers for weak_ptr. I had error:

error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘boost::weak_ptr’

Why? What should I do?

Comment: Don't use [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) directly. Use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). If you read the linked reference for `std::weak_ptr` you will learn why.

Answer (score 5):

First, lock the weak_ptr - if it's not expired, you'll get the appropriate `shared_ptr`:

```
shared_ptr<my_type> p = weak.lock();
if (p)
  p->do_something();
else
  // expired!
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to use `std::weak_ptr<T>` to maintain memory. In fact, it is used to release memory as soon as possible while being able to possible retrieve an object if it is used elsewhere. Depending on your ownership semantics, you want to use `std::unique_ptr<T>` for a single owner of the object or `std::shared_ptr<T>` for shared ownership of the object.

The idea of `std::weak_ptr<T>` is that you might have the need to find objects if they do exist but you don't want to cling onto these objects to strongly. That is, if there is no other owner, i.e., `std::shared_ptr<T>`, of an object, the object is released although there is a `std::weak_ptr<T>` pointing to it. The `std::weak_ptr<T>` gets informed about the other object being released, however. To use an object pointed to by a `std::weak_ptr<T>`, you need to convert it into a `std::shared_ptr<T>` after you made sure that it indeed points to an object which is still alive (if the object referenced from a `std::weak_ptr<T>` doesn't exist anymore when converting it to a `std::shared_ptr<T>`, an exception gets thrown).

The same semantics apply to the Boost versions of these class templates: the standard class templates are modeled after the Boost ones.

Comment: ... and just remember this: `weak_ptr` is _not_ a pointer (despite its name).